# If memories and knowledge could be kept, which year would be best to be "reborn" in?

Tags: economy, history, reincarnation

I'm trying to create a character that is given an option after his death to choose the exact year he wants to be reborn in with all his memories still there. However, he is not allowed to let anyone know about his previous life when it happens.

**Which year in the past would be best suited for that character to be reborn into to easily make a significant amount of money and live a carefree life using the memories from his past life?** He is not allowed to create and invent things from the future, only take advantage of events he knows will happen.

One example I could think of is (around) year 1990, so by the time the character grows up he can invest in bitcoin and have it pay off later. However that is a bit boring for a story, are there any more interesting and clever occurrences from the past where a person that could have known about them would be able to take great advantage for his own good?

Comment: Welcome to WB:SE.  This is an intriguing question, but I expect that it will be closed.  This is because you can be born into any year and take advantage of the following years' circumstances to become successful, powerful, or wealthy.  There is no single "best" investment that is better than any other.  In that regard, your question is about storybuilding, not worldbuilding, and therefore off-topic.

Comment: I'm not asking for the absolute best scenario, I just want to see if there are any especially interesting time periods for this set-up.

Comment: If my niece could be reborn in 1950 she might know that investing in Microsoft and Apple would be wise, but she would have no clues on how to practically live in those years

Comment: "I just want to see if there are any especially interesting time periods" - this would qualify this question as too broad and opinion based. There are many interesting periods, and without any restriction it's only a matter of opinion what is more interesting and what is less, and what is outright boring.

Answer (score 1):

## Halfway through his/her life

He will still remember the event that occurred during the second part of his old life (i.e. the first part of the new one), so he can take advantage of them. Then he still has half of a life of unknowns and surprises to not get bored. If he play it well, he will make enough money and connections in the first half to be ready for whatever comes in the second part.

The thing is, that the second (yet unknown) part could be much better for him, maybe they will invent immortality or space travel! If he reborn too much in the past, he might lose it. So it is sort of a balance between taking advantage of what you already know and taking the chance that something cool isn’t yet known.

He can also play with this, and if he wants to be more confident, reborn at 1/3 of his old life. Or more gambling and be reborn at 2/3, and so on.

## Some more fun

On the other hand, he can try to be reborn in a period full of opportunities, but way more in the past. Doesn’t he want to be the first European to visit the Americas? Or to add some fun feature in the pyramids plans? To discuss strategies matters with Caesar? Or simply to hunt some mammoths and watch the stars at night without light pollution?

Probably I would not want to relive my life (I like it, don’t worry, I’m just too curious). I’d rather ask them to wait and reborn me in 2000 years or so. If not possible, one of the options above.